How do I output text from python to my terminal such that when it is copy/pasted into slack it has links to jira tickets
This might not be doable...
I am trying to create a python script that will generate text that I can use as the base for my daily status update in slack...
It needs to have the ticket key as a link to the ticket.
I can use this
    # OSC 8 ; params ; URI ST <name> OSC 8 ;; ST
    escape_mask = '\033]8;{};{}\033\\{}\033]8;;\033\\'

    return escape_mask.format(parameters, uri, label)

To get links on the terminal.  But when copied to slack it loses the link.
